# Vagrant libvirt provider on Fedora 23

Tags: fedora, vagrant

I need to install `libvirt` Vagrant plugin but it fails with the following error:

```
$ vagrant plugin install libvirt
The plugin(s) can't be installed due to the version conflicts below.
This means that the plugins depend on a library version that conflicts
with other plugins or Vagrant itself, creating an impossible situation
where Vagrant wouldn't be able to load the plugins.

You can fix the issue by either removing a conflicting plugin or
by contacting a plugin author to see if they can address the conflict.

Vagrant could not find compatible versions for gem "ffi":
In Gemfile:
  libvirt (>= 0) ruby depends on
    ffi (~> 0.6.3) ruby

  ffi (1.9.10)
```

I use only `hostmanager` plugin. The error remains even after removing this plugin so I guess it must conflict with Vagrant itself.

Is it possible to modify the Gemfile of `libvirt` plugin to depend on `ffi 1.9.10`? How would I do that?

I had no problems on Fedora 21.

Also I don't know Ruby whatsoever. I just need this running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem.

1. The plugin is called `vagrant-libvirt` **NOT** `libvirt`
2. The installation of `vagrant-libvirt` fails too.

   I found this line in `~/.vagrant.d/gems/extensions/x86_64-linux/ruby-libvirt-0.6.0/mkmf.log`:

   > gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory

   The solution for this problem is easy: `dnf install redhat-rpm-config-36-1.fc23.noarch`.

After this, the installation completed successfully.